# Как создать свой кастомный row в visual composer?

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Добрый, помогите пожалуйста с шорткодом для visual composer.
Я создал пару кастомных элементов для вывода информации в пост, но ряд и секция в композер по умолчанию, можно ли как-то создать свой ряд или свою секцию, те кастомную обертку компонент для компонента.
Например я создал компонент слайдер и он выводит только слайды в цикле, в свое время компонент слайдер я кладу в компонент ряд или секцию, в идеале я бы хотел создать совю секцию со своими классами и своей струкрутой в дальнейшем в котрою я закину мой кастомный компонент slider.
Скрин кастомных компонентов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Скрин дефолтныхм компонентов: ряд и секция.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Надо делать свой шорткод. Я выносил куски кода в проекте таким шорткодом (в functions.php):

```
// Shortcode to output any post
function block_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $p = get_page_by_title($atts['title']);
    if ( function_exists('icl_object_id') ) {
        $id = icl_object_id( $p->ID, 'post', true );
        $p = get_post($id);
    }
    return do_shortcode($p->post_content);
}
add_shortcode('block', 'block_shortcode');
```

Функция получает название страницы и выводит ее содержимое целиком в то место, где указан шорткод. Код внутри if - для мультиязычного сайта с WPML. Если WPML не установлен, код внутри if будет проигнорирован.

Пример использования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шорткод [block title="название_страницы"] должен быть помещен в текстовый блок. В других блоках Visual Composer не обрабатывает шорткоды.

Comment: Спасибо но не совсем то, сделал по другому, в документации visual composer нашел ка создать компонент ряд и для компонента ряд компонент дочерний елемент.